# How to get JSON object from HTTP request in Java

Tags: java, json, httprequest

I'm now trying to get JSON Object with using HTTP request in Java cord.

I want to know how I can get response or JSON object in the following cord.

Please let me know.

(In this program, I try to get Wikipedia categories of the article "New York". )

```
 String requestURL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=json&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=10&titles=" + words[i];
 URL wikiRequest = new URL(requestURL);
 URLConnection connection = wikiRequest.openConnection();  
 connection.setDoOutput(true);  

                    /**** I'd like to get response here. ****/

 JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
```

Comment: Do NOT do this. You will get OOM's if the request is relatively big and it will be very hard to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(wikiRequest.openStream());
String response = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
scanner.close();
```

Comment: What library contains the Util class you are using? This answer might force the developer to include a new dependency that they might not want.

Comment: It was in the original question. I do not know what is behind. I reused it in my answer because if this method does what its name suggests then there is no reason to change it to something else (at least in the scope of this question).

Answer (score 4):

Just 2 lines of code with `JSONTokener`

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(wikiRequest.openStream());
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

Comment: URL.openStream() returns an InputStream... JSONTokener expects an String though?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using URLConnection you should be able to read the stream instead of getting a response object:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

Sample implementation with corn-httpclient & corn-converter

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new URI(http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=json&clshow=!hidden&cllimit=10&titles=" + words[i]));
HttpResponse response = client.sendData(HTTP_METHOD.GET);
if (! response.hasError()) {
String jsonString = response.getData();
JsTypeComplex jsonResponse =  (JsTypeComplex) JsonStringParser.parseJsonString(jsonString);
JsTypeList resultsArr = (JsTypeList) jsonResponse.get("results");
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-converter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```