# how to read JSON from HTTP GET request?

Tags: java, json, http, get

I have created a java server which gets HTTP GET request url as

```
/Star/getDetails?sentMsg=data.requestorName:ABC,data.companyName:EFG,portfolios:
[{name:,placeholder:Portfolio 1,positions:[{ticker:T1234,weight:29.85},
{ticker:T2345,weight:70.15}],active:false}],analyticsDate:20140630}
```

I have to parse `sentMsg` parameter such as I am able to read each variable individually. For eg, i should be able to read `data.requestorName`, `companyName`. I am not able to find a way to do it.

`request.getParameter("sentMsg")` always return `String`.

Tried parsing it through json-simple

```
   JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = jp.parse(sentMsg);
        JSONArray ja = (JSONArray)obj;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this gives parse exception. I have limitation to use `json-simple` jar only. Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901831/how-to-get-json-object-from-http-request-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Get the paramter sentMsg from HttpRequest object store it into a string. Split from comma i.e. "," and the last second token would be the json string. You can now parse it using Json simple lib and extract values from it.

Comment: I believe splitting it will "," will mess up the structure..note this positions:[{ticker:T1234,weight:29.85}..spiliting will not preserve positions array

Comment: Replace commas to some other character outside json.

Answer (score -1):

Provided you have valid JSON like:

```
private static String jsonString = "[{name : \"stackOverFlow\"}]";
```

Convert it to JSONArray like:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString );
```

Then you can get value out of JSONArray by looping through it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { //Iterating over mediaArray
    JSONObject media = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String nameFromJSON = media.getString("name");
    System.out.println("Name = " + nameFromJSON);
}
```

Output will be:

```
//Name = stackOverFlow
```

Comment: The problem is that he does **not** pass valid JSON to his parser.

Comment: also new JSONArray(jsonString ) is not supported by json.simple jar

Comment: Supported: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29