# Read JSON message from HTTP POST request in Java

Tags: java, json, http-post, embedded-jetty

I am new to Java and to client- server programming.

I am using embedded Jetty, and I'm trying to send a JSON string to some address (http://localhost:7070/json) and then to display the JSON string in that address.

I tried the following code but all I get is null.

Embedded Jetty code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(7070);
    ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/json");
    handler.addServlet(ExampleServlet.class, "/");
    server.start();
}
```

Client side function for sending the Http POST:

```
public static void sendHttp(){
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead 

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:7070/json");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("name", "MyName");
            object.put("age", "26");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        String message = object.toString();
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        // handle response here...
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
    }
}
```

And Servlet functions:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //System.out.println("test get\n");
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //System.out.println("test post\n");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        String json_str = req.getParameter("name");
        out.print(json_str);
    }
}
```

I call the sendHttp() method from a test class, after running the embedded Jetty server code (if that matters).

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901831/how-to-get-json-object-from-http-request-in-java

Answer (score 2):

To get the data from a Post request you need to obtain the content. Try this:

```
String data = IOUtils.toString(req.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Check if you have import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the raw request body as below. Put this inside your `doPost` method of `servlet` for reading `json` from the request:

```
StringBuilder jsonBuff = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
try {
    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jsonBuff.append(line);
} catch (Exception e) { /*error*/ }

System.out.println("Request JSON string :" + jsonBuff.toString());
//write the response here by getting JSON from jasonBuff.toString()

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jb.toString());

    out.print(jsonObject.get("name"));//writing output as you did

} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON ");
}
```

**Note :** You can access `req.getParameter("name");` only when your headers would be like this:

```
content type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

as in normal html form submission.

Comment: not sure I got it - do I need to change        
 request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); to         request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");?

Comment: No you follow the first method. That is using `req.getReader()`. I put `Note` as an additional info.

Comment: fromObject(jb.toString() Whyare you trying to make a JSONObject from an object then calling a string? Also jb is not defined. 10/10 for effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code this works fine

```
    String data = "";   
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
    data = builder.toString();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data); 
   //or JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data); which ever the one you want
```

Good luck.....

Answer (score 0):

I have not used jetty but I have done similar comunications with this code (PUT, not POST):

```
URL url = new URL(desturl);
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("PUT");
byte[] postData = null; 
int postDataLength; 
huc.setDoOutput(true);
postData = data.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
postDataLength = postData.length;
huc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json"); 
huc.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
huc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
huc.setUseCaches( false );
huc.connect();
huc.setConnectTimeout(10000);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( huc.getOutputStream());
wr.write( postData );
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));
retcode = huc.getResponseCode();
```