# Handling POST requests from a remote website/Sigfox with Jetty 9.4.1

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, payload

I'm new to Jetty and networking with Java so please bear with me and my beginners questions.

What I want to do is process a payload sent from Sigfox in the **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** format i.e. the data will come as "*device={device}&data={data}&time={time}*".

I've learnt that I can actually make a Sigfox Callback to a Java app server. Correct me if I'm wrong but I was thinking that a servlet can serve just the same purpose?
This is why I decided to embed Jetty into my Java application (I'm using the latest Jetty 9.4.1).

Following the [Embedded Jetty tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html) I've made this program:

```js
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;

public class MinimalServlets
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a basic jetty server object that will listen on port 9081.
        // Note that if you set this to port 0 then a randomly available port
        // will be assigned that you can either look in the logs for the port,
        // or programmatically obtain it for use in test cases.
        Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress("MY_IP", 9081));

        // The ServletHandler is a dead simple way to create a context handler
        // that is backed by an instance of a Servlet.
        // This handler then needs to be registered with the Server object.
        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        // Passing in the class for the Servlet allows jetty to instantiate an
        // instance of that Servlet and mount it on a given context path.

        // IMPORTANT:
        // This is a raw Servlet, not a Servlet that has been configured
        // through a web.xml @WebServlet annotation, or anything similar.
        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");

        // Start things up!
        server.start();

        // The use of server.join() the will make the current thread join and
        // wait until the server is done executing.
        // See
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()
        server.join();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from HelloServlet</h1>");
            
//            System.out.println("\nConnected");
//      System.out.println(request.getParameter("data"));

        }
        
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            // Get POST parameters
            String val = req.getParameter("data");
            System.out.println(val);    //print value of 'data'
            // Write a response
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);  //respond with "200"          
            resp.getWriter().printf("data = %s",val);
        }
    }
}
```

However it doesn't receive the payload from Sigfox nor does it respond with "200". On the Sigfox end it says the "connection has timed out":

[Screenshot of callback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5FN0.jpg)

From my reading of the Jetty architecture, HttpServlet and ServletHandler is the right way to go? So where am I going wrong with my understanding and code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other then not reading the data from the HttpServletRequest, the rest looks fairly normal.  Perhaps there's some logging output from Jetty that tells you what's going on.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt the only output I get on the eclipse console when I run this program is: "2017-02-16 12:50:46.528:INFO::main: Logging initialized *at sign*7037ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2017-02-16 12:50:47.891:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-02-16 12:50:48.893:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector*at sign*1f89fa3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{HOSTNAME.internal.local:9081}
2017-02-16 12:50:48.894:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started *at sign*9587ms"

Comment: If I'm correct the doPost() method should be the one that handles the POST request that comes from Sigfox, right? If I comment out the doGet() method so only doPost() is left, then I get the error on my URL: "HTTP ERROR 405
Problem accessing /. Reason:
    HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"

Comment: Does it matter is Sigfox is HTTPS? Can it still send payloads to my HTTP server?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896136/read-json-message-from-http-post-request-in-java) is similar to what I want to do but not in json code, just the normal **x-www-form-urlencoded**. Currently my doGet is executed instead of my doPost. doGet also says the request is coming from "/favicon.io"??? How do I fix this?